# How to upgrade from OpenEp6 to OpenErp7?

Tags: migration, upgrade, odoo

I'm newbie in OpenErp and i'm just using basic functionnalities of OpenErp6 and i want to upgrade to OpenErp7.
I'm using it under Ubuntu11..Is there a tool to upgrade it to The 7 version ?because i searched in google and i found that i must uninstall it manually and reinstall the latest version .

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your data, you have two ways of doing this:

1. get support from the OpenERP editor: they [sell a migration solution](http://v6.openerp.com/catalog/146), for a not very high price.
2. get in touch with and contribute to the [openupgrade](https://launchpad.net/openupgrade-addons) project which tries to build an opensource migration solution. The migration to 7.0 is not yet ready as of today, so you'll need either wait or contribute to get it good enough to migrate your instance.

On the other hand, if you have very little data as you mention in your comment, you can probably migrate by hand be creating a fresh OpenERP 7 instance, and manually recreating your entries in that instance. Obviously, this is not scalable.

Comment: Thank you very much , i don't need to keep the data because i have a backup

Comment: sidenote: if the answer is ok with you, don't hesitate to accept it. That the way this site works. Not accepting answers you think good is going to get you no answers at all.

Comment: The answer is good but it's not good enough for me, i'm looking for matching ansewer,anyway i will accept it

Comment: I'm not forcing you :-) If there are precisions you need to enhance the answer, please ask.